# 'FileName' does not contain a definition for '_field' and no extension method '_field' accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, declaration

I have spent that past few hours trying to fix these errors. I'm not sure why I am getting these declaration errors for _field. I have tried declaring at the top and within the scope and the error hasn't changed. I tired declaring _field as private too. If you could give an example of what the code snippet should be that would help a lot. I bolded where the error message takes place.

**Code:

```
public class FileClass
{
    #region '  Declarations  '

    private string TEMP_FILE = "~tmpData.txt";
    private GenericParserAdapter _parser;
    private int _fieldID;
    private int _profileID;
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private string _dataType = string.Empty;
    private int _length = 0;
    private Boolean _isKey = false;
    private Boolean _inCompare = false;
    private int _startPosition = 0;
    private int _endPosition = 0;
    public  int _field;

    public enum FileType
    {
        CharacterRanges,
        Delimited
    }


    private string _location = string.Empty;
    private FileType _type;
    private DataTable _data;
    private Boolean _firstRowContainsFieldNames = true;

    public class ProfileClass
    {

        public ProfileClass _profile = new ProfileClass();

    }




    public class FieldCollectionClass
    {
        private FieldCollectionClass _ComparisonFileOne = new FieldCollectionClass();
        private FieldCollectionClass _ComparisonFileTwo = new FieldCollectionClass();

    }

    #endregion

private void CreateDefaultFieldNames(DataTable ParsedTable)
{
    // ADD LINE COLUMN HEADER
    ParsedTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Line";

    // NAME COLUMN HEADERS
    for (int i = 0; i < this._profile._field.Count; i++)
    {
        FieldCollectionClass field = this._profile._field[i];

        ParsedTable.Columns[i + 1].ColumnName = field._name;

        this._fields.Add(field);
    }
}

private void BuildParser(Boolean IsFixedLengthFile)
{

    _parser.FirstRowHasHeader = this._firstRowContainsFieldNames;

    if (IsFixedLengthFile)
    {   
        _parser.FixedWidth = true;

        int[] columnWidths = new int[this._profile._field.Count];
        int index = 0;

        // BUILD COLUMN WIDTHS
        foreach (FieldClass field in this._profile._field)
        {
            columnWidths[index] = _field.Length;
            index++;
        }
        _parser.ColumnWidths = columnWidths;
    }
    else
    {
        _parser.SetColumnDelimiter(',');
    }
}

#endregion
```

Error:

> 'FileName' does not contain a definition for '_field' and no extension method '_field' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: FileName doesn't even exists in your example code...

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of this code?

```
public class ProfileClass
{

   public ProfileClass _profile = new ProfileClass();

}
```

How many instances do you think it will make?